# Insert Pictures by file path in document for hundreds of pages that match common name MS Access VBA

Tags: vba, ms-access

I have about 400 images that are in a separate directories by there name. I want to match these names with the filepath to the image attached to a report in access so the images will show up in access and I can print the report with the images included. I want to use VBA code as this is a repeating process and there are a lot of pages to insert a picture for otherwise done by hand.

I have some example data of my file paths. I have conditions. 
[image]

I would like these images to show up in access so that they look like this when I export them. Here is an example. Each image from left to right will correspond to the trait 1,2,3 as shown in the table.

In access I have tried using hyperlink by I can't get it to match the Name to the name in the report like a master and child link or something in VBA might work too.

test3

[image: test3]

[image: test2]

[image: test1]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like this should be a two step process for you.

1. Add image placeholders. Insert an image where you want it on the report. Choose an image that would clearly show the image didn't load so you know when it's broken. Like a big red X.
2. Replace that image using an event that will load automatically as you make reports

EXAMPLE EVENT CODE:

```
Private Sub Detail_Format(Cancel As Integer, FormatCount As Integer)
    Me![Imageframe].Picture = Me![Imagepath]
End Sub
```

Replace the name of the Imageframe with whatever you named your placeholder image. Replace the assignment with whatever contains your image path. You should be able to add as many of these as you want.

SOURCE:
http://www.databasedev.co.uk/bound_image_report.html